# bash: command line arguments as script triggers

Tags: bash, arguments

In my bash routine I am using two alternative methods to use arguments defined during the script execution and assign them to specific variables used by some other functions within the same script:

```
# tested and works OK
parse_args() { 
  MY_SORT_METHOD=1 # sort strings according the number of the ligand
  MY_FILT_METHOD=0 # filt data according to all strategies
  while (($#)); do
    case "$1" in
    --sort=*)
        IFS== read -r _ val <<<"$1"
        case "$val" in 1|2) ;; *)
              echo "Wrong value is set: please select either the 1st or 2nd method of sorting"
              return 1
        esac
        MY_SORT_METHOD="$val"
        ;;
    --filt=*)
        IFS== read -r _ val <<<"$1"
        case "$val" in [0-4]) ;; *)
              echo "Wrong value is chosen: please select one of four strategies of filtering (--filt=1,2,3,4). Othervise select all four strategies (--filt=0)"
              return 1
        esac
        MY_FILT_METHOD="$val"
        ;;
    esac
    shift
  done
}

# this does not work
parse_args2() { 
  args=$(getopt -o '' -l sort:,filt: -- "$@")
  eval "set -- $args"
  MY_SORT_METHOD=1
  MY_FILT_METHOD=0
  set -x
  while (($#)); do
     case "$1" in
     --sort) MY_SORT_METHOD="$2"; shift; ;;
     --filt) MY_FILT_METHOD="$2"; shift; ;;
     --) shift; break; ;;
     esac
     shift;
  done
}
```

While parse_args() is working OK, there is some bug in parse_args2(), which does not allow to execute this function in the simular fashion... What should I fix there, assuming that the both functions are called in the bash script just using using

```
parse_args $*
```

Also here is another function, which uses 4 different AWK scripts to process the same CSV file in the case if a variable defined in the argument is 0: "${MY_FILT_METHOD}" = "0":

```
filter_csv () {
  for d in "${storage}"/*/; do
   dir_name=${d%*/}
   dir_name=$(basename "$dir_name")
   [ "${MY_FILT_METHOD}" = "0" ] && awk -v min_lines=3 -F ", " 'a < $2 {for(idx=0; idx < i; idx++) {print arr[idx]} print $0; a=int($2); i=0; printed=NR} a > $2 && NR > 1 {arr[i]=$0; i++}END{if(printed <= min_lines) {for(idx = 0; idx <= min_lines - printed; idx++){print arr[idx]}}}' "${d}"/${dir_name}*_proc.csv > "${d}"/${dir_name}_str1.csv
   [ "${MY_FILT_METHOD}" = "0" ] && awk -v cut1="$cut1" -v cut2="$cut2" -F ', ' 'NR == 1 {next} FNR==NR {if (max < $2) {max=$2; n=FNR+1} next} FNR <= 2 || (FNR == n && $2 > (cut1 * max)) || $2 > (cut2 * max)' "${d}"/${dir_name}*_proc.csv{,} > "${d}"/${dir_name}_str2.csv
   [ "${MY_FILT_METHOD}" = "0" ] && awk -v cut3="$cut3" -v cut4="$cut4" -F ', ' 'NR == 1 {next} FNR==NR {if (maxP < $2) maxP=$2; if (minD=="" || minD > $3) minD=$3; next} FNR <= 2 || ($2 >= (cut3 * maxP) && $3 <= (cut4 * minD))' "${d}"/${dir_name}*_proc.csv{,} > "${d}"/${dir_name}_str3a.csv
   [ "${MY_FILT_METHOD}" = "0" ] && awk -v cut3="$cut3" -v cut4="$cut4" -F  ', ' 'NR == 1 {next} FNR==NR {if (maxP < $2) maxP=$2; if (minD=="" || minD > $3) minD=$3; next} FNR==2{p=$0} FNR == 1 || ($2 >= (cut3 * maxP) && $3 <= (cut4 * minD)) {++c; print} END {if (c==1) print p}' "${d}"/${dir_name}*_proc.csv{,} > "${d}"/${dir_name}_str3b.csv
done
```

Would it be possible rather to merge those 4 awk commands into one block activated by [ "${MY_FILT_METHOD}" = "0" ] && ?

Comment: Show how you invoke `parse_args2`, i.e. the script where you use these functions.

Comment: What's to prevent you from changing that to `if [ "$MY_FILT_METHOD" = "0" ]; then awk 1; awk 2; awk 3; awk 4; fi`?

Comment: Thanks nice idea!! And in the script the both functions are activated via parse_args $*

Comment: I would definitely concatenate those awk calls into a single one with some more defined conditional checks. A first step for me personally, would be to make variables declared inside a function to be `local`. This would be just a precaution. In your `if` statements that call the awk programs, you might change the single equals `=` signs to double equal signs `==`.

As to the `parse_args2()` function having a bug, it may be the way you are invoking that function that may be the problem. Can you edit the question to show how it is being called? That will clear it more for me.

Comment: Thank you! I've just edited my first post showing how I call the both functions (in fact the parse_args() works well using this syntax!) Regarding the variable, the idea is to declare as a global one, since it is used in another parts of the same script/ other functions (like the third function in my example)  BTW could you clarify what is the difference between =1 and ==1 in the IF condition? Actually, I have already tested it with '=' and it worked always fine.. Cheers